# respond_to :json ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am adding an api to an existing rails app that is not working like I want it to. I had the error below that I fixed with the fix below. I am looking for a proper explanation of why my original code was not working (was it working in older versions of rails? I'm on 4.2). I understand why the fix is working but does it have  any drawbacks to the original code.

My route:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, :only => [:show]
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat

Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

The fix:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render :json => @user
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it was not clear from the request url and header parameters which format your application should return.

In your first version the request url should end with `.json` or the request should have a HTTP Accept header with the value `application/json`. Otherwise there is no way to tell that this was a request that should return JSON data.

In your second version you just say: Hey, return this as JSON, no matter what format the request has.

Answer (score 2):

there was no bug you requested `/api/v1/users/1` which defaults to look for html.

You could make your intention clear calling: `/api/v1/users/1.json` or in your routes:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
```

Answer (score 2):

This is mean that you make request in unsupported format (in your case not in JSON). Look at [this code](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders/blob/c3e2d049e596bc0a76cbc0d1ef298de4926bed16/lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb#L205) for more details.

I think you forget to specify `Accept` header or add `.json` suffix at the end of your URL.